# User input value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code:

```
select  p.personID as "Person ID",
    p.personname as "Person Name",
    c.name as "City Name",
    h.dateArrived as "Date Arrived",
    y.Name as "Country Name"
from    country y
join    city c
on      c.CountryCode = y.Code
join    hasvisitedcity h
on      h.cityID = c.ID
join    person p
on      p.personID = h.personID
where y.Name LIKE '%i%'
Order by p.personID;
```

This works fine, but it has a hardcoded *LIKE* search function. I would like to add a method whereby the user can input a search parameter (say land), and the parameter would be passed to the second last line for matching.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have an example of how "land" would show up in this query? It's not clear what the difference would be versus "i" in this case.

Comment: You may be interested in the [full text search capability](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html) of MySQL as `LIKE` doesn't scale very well.

Comment: @tadman The user would enter a search parameter, which would be a variable, and it would then be passed to the script: where y.Name LIKE CONCAT('%',variable,'%')

Comment: Then sounds like you have a solution as far as the query goes. `CONCAT` is the right tool for the job there.

Comment: @tadman, my question is how do I get the user to be able to input a string they want searched

Comment: With MySQL alone you can't, it's not equipped to do that. You need a front-end of some sort, a script perhaps, which can be written in anything you want. C#, Python, Perl, Ruby, Node.js, if it has a MySQL driver you're good. You also really don't want to drop an ordinary user into a `mysql>` shell because they can cause irreparable harm with any number of commands.

Comment: Thanks, will have to look at those options